# How to use ActionResult in onkeyup and onkeydown in a input which type is number?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to use an action result in a input function,here is my code,my goal is that when user Keyup or keydown or type a number in input,Sum of ProductPrice changes.i dont know,which event is proper for my goal,i have used onkeydown & onkeyup events.but nothing changes.

```html
  <td><input type="number" onkeyup="@Url.Action("CountUp","ShoppingCart",new { id = @item.ProductId })"
                         onkeydown="@Url.Action("CountDown","ShoppingCart",new { id = @item.ProductId })"
                                                                 
                         value="@item.ProductCount" min="0"  style="width:70px"></td>
```

and Here is My controller

```
      // GET: ShoppingCart
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ShowShoppingCart> shopcart = new List<ShowShoppingCart>();
        if (Session["ShoppingCart"] != null)
        {
            List<ShopCartItem> shop = Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<ShopCartItem>;
            foreach (var item in shop)
            {
                var product = db.Products.Find(item.ProductId);
                shopcart.Add(new ShowShoppingCart()
                {
                    ProductCount = item.ProductCount,
                    ProductId = item.ProductId,
                    ProductPrice = product.ProductPrice,
                    ProductTitle = product.ProductTitle,
                    Sum = item.ProductCount * product.ProductPrice


                });
            }
        }
        return View(shopcart);
    }

  public ActionResult CountUp(int id)
    {

        List<ShopCartItem> shop = Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<ShopCartItem>;
        int index = shop.FindIndex(s => s.ProductId == id);
        shop[index].ProductCount += 1;
        Session["ShoppingCart"] = shop;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    public ActionResult CountDown(int id)
    {
        List<ShopCartItem> shop = Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<ShopCartItem>;
        int index = shop.FindIndex(s => s.ProductId == id);
        shop[index].ProductCount -= 1;
        if (shop[index].ProductCount == 0)
        {
            shop.Remove(shop[index]);
        }
        Session["ShoppingCart"] = shop;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

and this is ShopCart

```
    public class ShopCartItem
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
}
```

and another question?
when user type a number in input which event should i use? onChange()? or another?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about your main question, but about the second one, you should really use onChange()

Comment: thanks,about my first question,i have an invoice that include these items: product,size,count,price and sum.  when i click on count input,and i change it by keyup and keydown or type a number in it,i want sum changes properly,but it doesent change,this is my problem.